# how to fix No display name and $DISPLAY environment variable python error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a game about clicking a button to get sap(long story), you click a tkinter button, but when i tried to add it to flask but it kept saying "

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/4TRS/mysite/SAPGAME.py", line 2, in <module>
    window = tkinter.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2020, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable"
```

This is my code

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
button=tkinter.Button(window, text="Click to get sap", width=40)
button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
clickcount = 0
def onclick(event):
    global clickcount
    clickcount = clickcount + 1
    sap1 = clickcount
    sap = str(sap1)
    if clickcount >= 1:
        button.configure(text="You have " + sap + " saps")
button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", onclick)
window.mainloop()
```

I want to be able to simply click the button. when I do it in IDLE it works just fine but when i try it on any online IDE it has the same error. I have been at this for hours and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

tkinter is GUI kit for desktop apps, it is not for use with web like Flask.

Because most online IDE's run the user code in confined environment (container) which don't have X11 server running.

It is too risky to run user custom code directly in the server, so that a security feature. However, I could find one that support Python tkinter emulation: https://create.withcode.uk/

[image: python online ide - tk support]

Comment: how do I fix it?

Comment: @LukeBarrett tkinter is not web apps , updated my answer